# Allegro Webactions not serving on SBCL. Methods to debug or possible solutions?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro

I am trying to get Portable Allegro Serve and Webactions up and running on SBCL. I have so far managed to make paserve properly serve pages. But webactions chunks out with the following warning in the console:

```
1-aserve-worker: 05/27/09 - 21:28:43 - processing clp file "/home/user/pages/index.html"  got error The value NIL
                                                                 is not of type
                                                                   FUNCTION.
1-aserve-worker: 05/27/09 - 21:28:43 - while processing command "GET /testing/index.html HTTP/1.0"
got error The slot NET.ASERVE::OBJECTS is unbound in the object #<NET.ASERVE:CLP-ENTITY {C1C8201}>.
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Alternatively any ideas on how I could break into this to examine/investigate what is going on?

Versions of software: SBCL 1.0.28 running on debian 2.6.26, PAServe 1.2.47.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the acl-compat library which comes with asdf-install is different from the acl-compat library that comes with paserve.

I never resolved the above problem, but using a different acl-compat layer made the problem disappear.